# How to check if CancellationTokenSource timer lanched?

Tags: c#, .net, cancellationtokensource

How can I check if CancellationTokenSource timer lunched?

Let's say I lunched my CancellationTokenSource object somewhere in my code:

```
_cancelTokenSrc.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));
```

And I want to test this line, in what way can I do it?

Comment: Check the token's `IsCancellationRequested`, the same way you would for any kind of cancellation. Many asynchronous methods will throw if their CancellationToken is signaled anyway

Comment: According to [CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter), "The countdown for the delay starts during this call."

Comment: Is the *real* question how to test without waiting for 60 minutes?

Comment: You can also add a callback `_cancelTokenSrc.Token.Register(() => {/* Cancelled */})`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Regarding your first note, IsCancellationRequested was false before and after lunching CancelAfter(..), so this is not a good way to test it.
Regarding your second note, no, I just need to check that the timer lunched. I'm not going to check the code of .Net

Comment: It's the *only* way to test it, because that's what it's for.. A CancellationTokenSource exists to create signal cancellation tokens. If it doesn't trigger, something else is wrong. 60 minutes is far too long. Most likely, your application has shut down due to inactivity, especially if you have an ASP.NET Core application

Comment: So what does *your code* do? Why do you think the CTS isn't working? Have you tried with a *short* interval like 1-2 seconds? Do you have actual code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: You're claiming that a fundamental feature of .NET Core isn't working. If that was the case, everybody would notice. Post code that actually demonstrates the problem

Comment: Panagiotis, this code taken from my company's project. I can't share it. We have a token of 60 minutes and I just need to test that the timer lunched, when I call the method it located in.
I'm not claiming that a fundamental feature of .NET Core isn't working.

Comment: You can't do this without reflecting over the private bits of `CancellationTokenSource`, which would be very brittle. For debugging purposes, you are better off adding your own `bool` to track if you called `CancelAfter` and inspecting that. If you're doing this in many places with many CTSes, you can consider using a wrapper class or a `ConditionalWeakTable`.